# How to use PyGithub with Streamlit to build a webapp

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to create a script that deploys with Streamlit in python that lists the contents of a specific repository. Is it even possible? because I'm trying it and it always says this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Github' from 'github' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/github/__init__.py)
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 564, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Users/blanc/Desktop/My-notes/webpage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from github import Github
```

I have literally this import that works with output in console:

```
from github import Github
```

I've checked like 18 times that I have the requeriments intalled(and the correct version of PyGithub) and I don't know what else can I do.
Hope you can help me :)

This is the code I'm using:

```
from github import Github

def list_content_repo():
    g = Github()
    # github username
    username = g.get_user("gitblanc")
    # Obtain the repository
    repo = username.get_repo("Obsidian-Notes")
    print(repo.get_contents(""))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How many python do you have on your computer?

Comment: I only have python 3.9

Comment: I added the code I'm using

Comment: Check your folder if there is a file named `github.py`.

Comment: It is not. The file is called webpage.py

Comment: Open command prompt, and type `pip freeze`, let's see if there is `pygithub` and `streamlit`.

Comment: I have both installed (pygithub 1.57, sreamlit 1.15.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know that I don't have issues with [pygithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) and [streamlit](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit).

### Code

`main.py`

```
from github import Github
import streamlit as st


def list_content_repo():
    g = Github()
    username = g.get_user("gitblanc")
    repo = username.get_repo("Obsidian-Notes")
    contents = repo.get_contents("")

    st.write('#### Contents')
    st.write(contents)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_content_repo()
```

### Output

[image]

### Setup

Try to setup your development environment this way. Let us see if you still have an issue. I am using windows 10 and use virtual environment. Open powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\ferdi> f:
```

I use drive f.

```
PS F:\> mkdir temp_streamlit

PS F:\> cd temp_streamlit
PS F:\temp_streamlit> python --version
Python 3.10.6

PS F:\temp_streamlit> python -m venv myvenv

PS F:\temp_streamlit> ./myvenv/scripts/activate

(myvenv) PS F:\temp_streamlit> python -m pip install pip -U

(myvenv) PS F:\temp_streamlit> pip install streamlit

(myvenv) PS F:\temp_streamlit> pip install pygithub
```

Create main.py using the above code and run streamlit.

```
(myvenv) PS F:\temp_streamlit> streamlit run main.py
```

You should see the same output above.